# Azure migrating Load Balancer to Standard tier with no downtime

Tags: azure, migration, virtual-machine, azure-load-balancer

Hello I have Virtual Machine Scale Set behind Load Balancer Basic and I would like to migrate to Load Balancer Standard tier. Is it possible with no downtime, or do I have to simply remove backend LB pool for basic and afterwards create backend pool for my VMSS within the LB Standard?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't add multiple load balancers to VMSS, the only alternative you'd have for no downtime would be to place an alternative load balancer there for a while.

Build an HA PRoxy box out front, configure it to load balance your apps, switch over DNS to the new IP. When DNS has propagated delete old load balancer, build new one. switch back.

If you're using the frontend IP rather than DNS, then I can't think of a way to do this without downtime. But swapping frontend IP to a temp VM would be quicker than deleting / recreating an LB.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for suggestion, we wanted to do it exactly this way, but unfortunately VMSS does not support to bind more LB to the same backend pool.

Comment: @marek_lani I suspected that when I wrote it, but I was in a cafe having breakfast, so didn't do my research! There's another idea though

Comment: Thanks Michael , as workload running on the VMSS is stateless we ended up with new VMSS cluster with app deployed and App Gateway in front so basically your suggestion with HA Proxy. Thanks.